# Salary calc app code wont run

Tags: python, calculator

i'm trying to make a calculator application that works out and displays the salary and wage in multiple ways but my functions wont run. i get no error messages and the first 'input' works but after that it seems like my functions don't activate. i have tried to manually activate the functions by removing the "if", and "elif" statements and just putting the name of the function.

```
know = input("Enter the letter for the category you know. if you know how much you earn per hour type '1'. if you know how much you earn per week type '2'. if you know your salary type '3'")

def wage():
a = input(int("How much do you earn per Hour?"))
b = input(int("How many hours do you work per day?"))
c = input(int("How many days do you work per week?"))
hour = ("you earn £",a, "per hour")
day = ("you earn £",a*b, "per day")
week = ("you earn £",day*c, "per Week")
year = ("your salary is £",week*52, "per year")
print (hours)
print (day)
print (week)
print (year)

def week():
a = input(int("How much do you earn per week?"))
b = input(int("how many hours do you work per day?"))
c = input(int("how many days do you work per week"))
hour = ("you earn £",(a/c)/c, "per hour")
day = ("you earn £",hour*b, "per day")
week = ("you earn £",day*c, "per week")
year = ("your salary is £",week*52, "per year")
print (hours)
print (day)
print (week)
print (year)

def year():
a = input(int("how much do you earn per year?"))
b = input(int("how many hours do you work per day?"))
c = input(int("how many days do you work per week"))
hours = ("you earn £",((a/52)/7)/b, "per hour")
day = ("you earn £",hour*b, "per day")
week = ("you earn £",day*c, "per week")
year = ("your salary is £",week*52, "per year")
print (hours)
print (day)
print (week)
print (year)

if know == "1":
wage
elif know == "2":
week
elif know == "3":
year
else:
print("I'm Confused")
```

if anybody could help me it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change `wage`, `week`, and `year` in your if-else to `wage()`, `week()`, and `year()` to actually execute the functions:

```
if know == "1":
    wage()
elif know == "2":
    week()
elif know == "3":
    year()
else:
    print("I'm Confused")
```